# Tracking visitors

Tags: php, jquery, tracking, visitor-pattern

I have a video embedded in a third party blog. Is it possible to track how a visitor landed up in that blog and viewed my video. Can you please give some guidance as to how this can be achieved.

Please note I don't have access to the analytic of the third party blog. It is only my video which has been embedded into that blog.

Comment: what do you mean by "how"? the referer?

Comment: Yes I meant how to track the site from which the visitor landed into the blog.

Comment: Negin I am totally clueless. Any directions will help

Comment: @Ram, do you have access to the blog files? Where is the blog hosted?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) or even [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

Comment: he mentioned he has embedded video on a third party blog, so it depends if he has access to place the stat code in the source.

Comment: Tudor correct me if I am wrong. From your reply I understand if I add Google Analytics to my video and embed into a third party website I will know how visitors come to the third party website to view my video.

Comment: Roman I dont have access to place stat code into the third party blog. The owner of the site is different. I only own the video.

Comment: Does your flash movie player have options for integrating some analytics code? Flowplayer offers you this possibility - http://flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/analytics.html

Comment: Yes my movie player has option to integrate analytics code but will it help to track visitors to a site who only has embedded my video.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why it is offering you this possibility

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible without embedding any kind of tracking code to that specific page. If you have access to that page, you need to install some third party stat counter code, such as Google Analytics or Statcounter etc.

Comment: No Roman I dont have access to the third party stat counter. I have updated my question to reflect that.